# Porque tengo que poner dos referencias a las API de GoogleMaps?

Tags: google-maps

esta es una de muchas preguntas o consultas que tengo sobre la implementacion de Google Maps en una página web. La primera de ellas es que introduciendo la siguiente linea con mi APIKEY el mapa NO SE MUESTRA:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=BLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLA&callback=initMap" async defer></script>
```

En cambio si agrego esta otra linea antes, si se muestra !!!

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
```

Viendo con F12 me dice que he incluido muchas veces la api de google maps... El código que tengo armado es el siguiente:

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Mapa</title>
<style>
  #map-canvas {
    height: 800px;
    width: 100%;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #888;
  }
 </style>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
 <!--<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=BLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLA&callback=initMap" async defer></script>-->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@MNibor la referencia js?sensor=false" ya no es necesario utilizarla en la versión mas reciente de Google Maps.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#sensor-not-required

```
SensorNotRequired   :   
El parámetro sensor ya no es obligatorio para la Google Maps 
JavaScript API. No evitará que Google Maps JavaScript API funcione en 
forma correcta, pero te recomendamos eliminar el parámetro sensor del 
elemento del script.
```

Practicamente cuando colocas los dos scripts estas duplicando la misma referencia.

Te dejo un ejemplo básico de un mapa. https://jsfiddle.net/api/post/library/pure/

```js
var map;
function initMap() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
    zoom: 8
  });
}
```

```css
/* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
 * element that contains the map. */
#map {
  height: 100%;
}
/* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="map"></div>
<!-- Replace the value of the key parameter with your own API key. -->
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCK3ulYYM8GCwK-_HlZVNKvkgp-zvEebUM&callback=initMap"></script>
```

Comment: Gracias @raintrooper... te hago otra consulta el tema de la key de la api... es necesario que esté oculta y no aparezca en el código de la página ? estuve leyendo algo por ahi en la documentación de google maps donde recomiendan esconder el código api

Comment: Toda la configuración de seguridad de las API de Google la debes realizar en la consola de desarrollador de Google y dependiendo de la API que utilices, por ejemplo, para proteger el uso de la "Google Maps Javascript API" debes configurar las peticiones de acceso ya sea para que acepte peticiones desde algunas IP's o desde algunos dominios, una vez que restrinjas o filtres las peticiones que se hagan con tu API KEY no debes preocuparte por que sea pública.